# Does mingw allow executing byte array without page_execute?

Tags: c, winapi, memory, mingw-w64

I looked in metasploit meterpreter source code and found that it executes the shell code by casting it to a function pointer without setting page protect as page_execute , I also saw some sources on github doing this like nullcrypter and
But in visual studio if I try this it causes access violation as said in microsoft documentation so is this something special for mingw or there is some trick behind

Comment: Show at least some code.

Comment: Here is some code on github in structure.c file :   https://github.com/Null-Sec/NSTools/tree/master/Null-Crypter%20(MSF)

Comment: and this is another one from venom project on gitbub :   https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/venom/blob/master/templates/exec.c

Comment: On Windows you cannot execute data.  The subject is pretty large.

Comment: But these code work on windows without any problem when compiling with mingw on linux , may mingw do some work visual studio don't ?

Comment: Any help here ?

Answer (score 0):

> without setting page protect as page_execute

This is incorrect; from your code:

```
unsigned char* exec = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, PAYLOAD_LENGTH/2 ,0x1000,0x40);
//...
((void (*)())exec)();
```

Notice that the last parameter of [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) is `0x40`, i.e. [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx), so you are getting memory that is already executable from the start, regardless of the compiler. MinGW does nothing special in this regard, the executable bit is already ok as it is.

If this code fails with VC++ it is probably due to some other incompatibility - maybe you are compiling in 64 bit mode when the payload code is 32 bit?

Comment: but in venom project there is no any use of virtualalloc or virtualprotect